# How can I make a shiny/glossy material that resembles these images?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

In the pictures you can see on the places where light comes, the blue is lighter. That's how I want it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In my case it is only a bit brighter and not really light blue.
[image]

I have also tried with Fresnel but that is not exactly what I want.
[image]

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: It looks like you're just starting with blender, this is a pretty common issue to run into.  It comes down to lighting and materials, suggest you look into some lighting tutorials and stick to just the principled bsdf until you're more comfortable.  There's a lot of control built into it, and actually your node setup is somewhat paradoxical :p

Comment: The principles are exactly the same as filming an actor on camera - you have control over the number, power, and placement of the lights. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBt8qdO03-k

Answer (score 3):

**Shader**

For such a game graphics/toon style your shader looks promising.

I would replace the *Principled BSDF* with a simple *Diffuse BSDF* and the *Fresnel* with a *Layer Weight* node, plus a *Color Ramp* for more control. The [Pointiness group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHIyK.jpg) just adds some color variation to the base color.

[image: shader]

**Lights**

For the lights try a so-called "tri-point lights" setup. Blender comes with the add-on "*Lighting: Tri-lighting*" that creates and places three lights for you. Activate the add-on in the preferences. Of course, you can add another light or two if you want.

[image: lights]

Experiment with the position, the strength (3x 150W, 400W in the example), and the color of the lights.

"Sonic Suzanne" (Cycles)
[image: render result]

Comment: Sunic, gotta go fast